Plural/singular regarding subject of two people
I'm confused by this sentence:
This image isn't real. The skin color of the mother and child respectively are wrong.
This image isn't real. The skin color of the mother and child respectively is wrong.
I believe skin color can't be written as skin colors, otherwise it would be clear to me to use are wrong.
The first sentence makes sense because mother and child is plural. But the second sentence also makes sense because skin color is singular. Which is correct?

What's the word respectively doing there? It makes no sense, and simply confuses the plurality issue.

I’m voting to close this question because the example text is semantic and syntactic nonsense

...but without the word respectively, if the mother and child are different colours the word colours must be plural to match the verb are. If it's just the same colour common to both bodies (but unrealistic), it's singular.

Why can't I use the word respectively? It means it is different for the mother and child.

It's not what "respectively" means.  You would use it to say (for example) "The skin colour and hair colour of the mother and child respectively"  to mean "the skin colour of the mother and the hair colour of the child"


[1] *This image isn't real. The skin color of the mother and child respectively are wrong.


[2] This image isn't real. The skin color of the mother and child respectively is wrong.

Example [1] is ungrammatical; the subject isn't mother and child.
Example [2] is unrealistic; the skin colours are almost certainly different.  Hence we use the plural colours and consequently are:

This image isn't real. The skin [colours] of the mother and child are wrong.

I have removed respectively.
Edit
If we must retain the adverb respectively, we would need a reconstruction like this, but such wordiness is
unnecessary unless those details need to be described.

This image isn't real. The displayed lighter skin colour and the tanned one for the mother and the child, respectively, are wrong.

Here colour and one together make the subject plural.

You spelled colors wrong.

Both are correct.   Usually I spell in BrE.

I don't understand. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/color

Collins Dictionary says REGIONAL NOTE:  in AM, use color.  Cambridge also says colour noun UK (US color).  We should try to consult more than one dictionary.

Well considering America is the wealthiest and most powerful country in the world, it only makes sense to follow American standards.

Rubbish. English speakers use the variety of English that is normal for the region they live in, or the variety they were taught.

@KateBunting: Obviously all things being equal you, me, and Seowjooheng naturally write colour every time. But (especially in potentially ephemeral comments) it can get a bit tedious ensuring consistency when we're copying and pasting bits of text from others. Maybe we can persuade the Stack Exchange "backroom boys" (the techies) to provide us with a "1-click" option to regularize / regularise all text in the current block. I've given up trying to persuade my Firefox browser to spellcheck agains BrE rather than AmE.

I can't accept british english because you have independent boarding schools that perpetuate class discrimination, so I'm always going to insist on proper American spelling.

The expanded versions of various dictionaries, most clearly Webster's, tell me that at the time of migration from Britain not only were both spellings valid but often, what's become the US American choice was preferred.
That aside Ronald et al might like to note, while context is king, I suspect we're talking here about US America. Simple 'America' at least includes Canada, even if it doesn't mean the 'the Americas' including everywhere from Mexico down to Argentina.

@ronaldchristenkkson If purely political Comments were allowed here, how would you counter the suggestion that the US, like every other country in the Americas, has independent boarding schools which perpetuate class discrimination? Doesn't that leave your reason for always insisting on proper American spelling clinging to a rather shaky limb with very thin ice below?
